# How to insert table in Databricks using magic SQL operator

Tags: sql, pyspark, databricks

I have create the following SQL table in databricks (using the magic %sql) as follows:

```
%sql
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  id INT
 ,name STRING
 ,met_area_name STRING
 ,state STRING
 ,type STRING
) USING CSV
```

I am now trying insert data into the table using the following command:

```
%sql
INSERT INTO TABLE mytable VALUES (id,name,type)
  SELECT DISTINCT criteria1, criteria2, 'b'
  FROM tablex
  WHERE somecriteria1 = 0
  ORDER BY somecriteria2;
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
mismatched input 'FROM' expecting <EOF>(line 2, pos 2)

== SQL ==
INSERT INTO TABLE mytable VALUES (id,name,type)
  FROM tablex
--^^^
  WHERE somecriteria1 = 0
  ORDER BY somecriteria2
```

I'm sure there is something very obvious that I'm missing, but I can't see it.

Any assistance much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: There is no SELECT line in your error log. Please check INSERT statement

Comment: oh wow, I don't know how I missed the SELECT line in the error log.. Anyhow, here is the full error ```Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
mismatched input 'SELECT' expecting <EOF>(line 2, pos 2)

== SQL ==
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (id,name,type)
  SELECT DISTINCT criteria1, criteria2, 'b'
--^^^
  FROM tablex
  WHERE somecriteria1 = 0
  ORDER BY somecriteria2```

Comment: I'm sure its something very simple that I'm missing....

Comment: There appears to be something wrong with my SELECT statement ...

Comment: According this [doc](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/insert.html#insert-from-select-queries), you don't need to use `VALUES` statement. Try to remove it

Comment: when I remove 'VALUES' I get the following error: ```== SQL ==
INSERT INTO searchBoxResponder (id,name,type)```
--------------------------------------------------^^^

Comment: the up arrows are pointing to (id,name,type) as the error

Comment: You have to remove `(id,name,type)` with `VALUES`

Comment: But the values are coming from the FROM tablex.

Comment: When enter the exact same commands in regular T-SQL from MS SQL it works fine. It should work with databricks

Comment: This should be so simple :-), but I just can't figure it out...

Comment: I definitely think you cannot mix `VALUES` and `SELECT` in the same `INSERT` statement

Comment: You can try fill other filelds (met_area_name, state) and execute following sql: `INSERT INTO TABLE mytable SELECT DISTINCT criteria1, criteria2, '', '', 'b' FROM ...`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand

Comment: @IskuskovAlexander, that didn't work.

Comment: Some errors?...

Comment: @Carltonp I think you could test the  query in SSMS or other tools to if there's the grammatical error.

Comment: Hi guys, I've tested in SSMS and it works fine

Comment: I'm on a call with Databricks engineers trying to fix this... they're actually looking at solutions from stackoverflow... this is not an easy fix. Been on the call with them for 3:20 (that is 3 hours and 20mins so far)

Comment: Hi @Carltonp, if the error solved, please share  us the solution, thank you!

Comment: Hi. please bear with me. Databricks have provided a solution I will share it with it you as soon as I get back to my desk.